# Angstrom Toolchain

Tags: angstrom-linux

I am new to angstrom and linux. I am in the process of building an sdk with angstrom. But I cant understand what is a **Toolchain** and its functionality. Please someone help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In software, a toolchain is the set of programming tools that are used to create a product (typically another computer program or system of programs). The tools may be used in a chain, so that the output of each tool becomes the input for the next, but the term is used widely to refer to any set of linked development tools.

A simple software development toolchain consists of a compiler and linker to transform the source code into an executable program, libraries to provide interfaces to the operating system, and a debugger.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain

Comment: This means these are some supporting objects